# Android Custom close button for notification

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

Hey I would like to create a custom notification I would like it to look like the sound cloud notification more specifically the x on the top right corner for closing also when I scroll from left to right I don't want the notification to be removed. Here is the image of sound cloud notification.

[image]

Comment: You have to use RemoteViews and make Your own layout. Look here for example, it shows not what You want, but how to do....http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a custom notification I would like it to look
>   like the sound cloud notification

In order to create a **custom notification** you just need to provide a custom XML layout to the [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529234/creating-a-notification-for-mediaplayer-with-an-android-foreground-service)).

> when I scroll from left to right I don't want the notification to be
>   removed

To achieve this you just need to invoke [`startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) on your playback `Service` by passing your custom notification. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144499/2760919) an example.